# Objective-C - Is the Pointer to a Class different from a pointer to another Class?

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing some experiments have come up with something like this:

```
MyClass<aProtocol> *anInstance;
```

later in the code for various reasons:

```
anInstance = [[MyFilterClass alloc] init];
```

All the compiler does is produce a warning.

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'MyClass<aProtocol> *' from 'MyFilterClass *'
```

Will this affect the program in any way I can't figure out yet?

Is does work now as the MyFilterClass was designed with this in mind.

Comment: What's the compiler warning?  Show the declaration of `aProtocol` and `MyFilterClass`.  It's all very vague.

Comment: What's the warning? This looks perfectly fine to me, unless you're not using ARC.

Comment: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'MyClass<aProtocol> *' from 'MyFilterClass *' The implementation of MyFilterClass is very simple with -(id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector, essentially I want send some of the messages destined to anInstance and route them somewhere else. I'm using ARC, what would happen if I weren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass` and `MyFilterClass` are different classes, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

If they both conform to `aProtocol` then declare the variable as:

```
id<aProtocol> *anInstance;
```

and then both these assignments will be possible:

```
anInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
anInstance = [[MyFilterClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Hmm... the id<aProtocol> *anInstance; is interesting, and does bring open up some new ideas. Thanks.